# i uploaded my Frontend and Backend to heroku i can't send post to heroku Backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

i uploaded my app FrontEnd and Backend on Heroku now i want to send fetch POST method to Backnd but not working but on Localhost is Work.

my FrontEnd

```js
    const checkoutSession = await fetch('https://e-commerce-shopping-1.herokuapp.com/payment', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            products: products,
            email: email !== null ? email : displayName
        })
    });
```

my Backend

```
<!-- language: express -->

   if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
     app.use(express.static('clients/build')) //Build File on FrontEnd(Reactjs);
   }
    app.post("/payment", cors(), async (req, res) => {
      // Get Request HERE......
      const { products, email } = req.body;
    });
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, () => console.log("Server Start"));
```

my Heroku Logs

2021-07-04T15:50:24.411072+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/payment" host=e-commerce-shopping-1.herokuapp.com request_id=d7841ecf-f2ec-40f8-9e31-b280fc41c46d fwd="129.208.175.233" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30005ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https

Comment: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules.

Comment: Have you tested to make sure it works locally?

Comment: Don't you have CORS errors in your networks activity ?

Comment: yes work locally correct

Comment: I can see the answer from Heroku service returns code 503 (status=503). This might indicate an error during the deploy of your app. I would suggest to add a simple /get endpoint that returns just 'ok' and check if you can get the result back once is deployed to Heroku:

app.get("/hello",  res => {
return res.send({"hello":"world"}});